# Cycles : how can I setup a glass material that doesn't become too dark when it is stacked?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I'm working on a picture where I need to stack layers of glass (the floors of a building).

The glass materials are tinted.  The goal is that you could read cleary and distinctly the color of each floor when viewing the picture.

I did some tests, but the thing is that the picture gets very dark when there is a lot of glass in the depth :

[image]

I also did some tweaks but cannot find something that works well.
Among others, I did try mixing an emitter node with my glass.
It reduces shadows but it doesn't look like glass anymore...

Could anyone explain me how I could do that ?  Here's [the project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bgp2nc9e68ajma6/buildingTest.blend?dl=0).

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe increase the light bounces

Comment: I feel its only dark in that area because it is the shadow of the middle perpendicular column?

Comment: @icYou520 : yes, probably, but anyway I need to have it brighter :)